# Transfer only a part of properties in a class in struts' json

Tags: json, struts2, actioncontroller

Sorry, I really don't know how to summarize the title of this question. So, the title may not be clear.

I have an action class which performs some business logic.

in the Action Class:

```
class ActionClass extends ActionSupport{
      private Merchandise merchandise;// I want to transfer it to the client
      //setter and getter

}
```

in the Merchandise class:

```
class Merchandise{
    private String name; // I want to transfer it
    private String price; //I don't want to transfer it
    private String description;//I don't want to transfer it
    //setter and getter
}
```

Now, I need to transfer the *merchandise* property in *ActionClass* to the client.

However, in the *merchandise* property, I want to transfer only the *name* property while inhibiting the other two properties.

Then how to inhibit the transfer of the other two properties(price and description) in class Merchandise?

Comment: can you explain more on "I want to filter those properties and transfer only a portion of them" with some example if possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<!-- Result fragment -->
<result type="json">
  <param name="root">merchandise</param>
  <param name="excludeProperties">price,description</param>
</result>
```

See full documentation, other options and examples at http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html

Comment: Really thanks, it seems I haven't digest the document enough, yet. Need more work. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a Data Transfer Object in your action class that contains only the fields you want to send to the client and make that your root object

Answer (score 0):

@nmc answer is correct another way you can try like:

```
<result type="json">
  <param name="root">merchandise</param>
  <param name="includeProperties">name</param>
</result>
```

Or

```
    <result type="json">
     <param name="includeProperties">
       merchandise.name
     </param>
     <param name="root">
       #action
     </param>
    </result>
```